# Can we send json object in batches?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have a big JSON and i need to send that in batches of 1MB. How can i do that in python??. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code.

Value is the whole big JSON.

```
for key, value in attributeJs.iteritems() :
                data = value
                headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
                try:
                        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
                        r = requests.post(url=URL_ATTRIBUTE, headers=headers, verify=False, data=data, timeout=(15,20))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a chunk encoded request by sending your data as a generator, something like this:

```
def generator():
    for key, value in attributeJs.iteritems():
        yield value

headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
           'Transfer-encoding':'chunked'}

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
r = requests.post(url=URL_ATTRIBUTE, headers=headers, verify=False, 
data=generator(), timeout=(15,20), stream=True)
```

and to get 1MB at a time:

```
r.iter_content(chunk_size=1000000)  # 1MB = 1000000 Bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stream the data, using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads)

```
with open('massive-body', 'rb') as f:
    requests.post('http://some.url/streamed', data=f)
```